# Passing values by form to create a query

Tags: taxonomy, query, forms, terms

I have this structure:

```
taxonomy
    - term1
    -- child term1
    -- child term2

    -term2
    -- child term1
    -- child term2
```

I have two select boxes. First one shows the parent terms (term1 and term2) and the second one shows the childs of the selected parent.

I submit the form to "search-results.php". How can I get the values of both selects to create this kind of query?

```
$args = array(
   'tax_query' => array(                        
       array(
          'taxonomy' => 'state',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => array( term1, childTerm2 ),
          'operator' => 'IN'
       )
    )
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you're trying to do it. When it comes to filtering results, i usually setup the form to use $_GET and filter the results when the page loads again:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $term = $_GET['term'];
} else {
    $term = 'defaultTerm';
}

if (isset($_GET['childterm'])) {
    $childterm = $_GET['childterm'];
} else {
    $childterm = 'defaultChild';
}

$args = array(
   'tax_query' => array(                        
       array(
          'taxonomy' => 'state',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => array( $term, $childterm ),
          'operator' => 'IN'
       )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but... if $childterm is null because de user has not selected nothing in the second select box?

Comment: you can use `$childterm = ''` instead of `'defaultChild'` for that, so that the query will bypass the empty positions on the array.